# How to put images behind each other in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this layout I have 3 responsive images that are displayed one after each other. But as I am trying to create an image slider, ideally I want only one image to appear and the rest would be hidden behind that image.
There goes my html:

```
<header>
    <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cell Phone</span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> WEBSITE</span>          
</header>           
<!------------Navigation area--------------------------->
<div class="logo">
    <img src="" alt="Image">
</div>
<nav>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONSULTING SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>         
<!------------Slide Section---------------------------->              
<section id="slider">
    <img src="image/291H.jpg" alt="Important Images">
    <img src="image/305H.jpg" alt="PIGS">
    <img src="image/251H.jpg" alt="ROADS will be here">
</section>
```

And the css code for the slider section and the image is as it goes:

```
img{
    width:100%;
}
#slider{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

How can I solve this problem and remain the responsiveness?

Comment: z-index is your friend here

Comment: use z-index - make sure you also add position:relative; to make sure it takes z-index into account otherwise your z-index wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have them in the same container (`#slider`) you can display them as `position: absolute` and they will be positioned on the top-left corner of its container.

I have created an example in which they dissapear when you click on them. Now you will have to hide/display them as your slider needed with `JQuery`.

```js
$('img').each(function() {
     $(this).click(function() {
       $(this).hide();
     });
});
```

```css
img{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}
#slider{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <span><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cell Phone</span>
    <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> WEBSITE</span>          
</header>           
<!------------Navigation area--------------------------->
<div class="logo">
    <img src="" alt="Image">
</div>
<nav>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONSULTING SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>         
<!------------Slide Section---------------------------->              
<section id="slider">
    <img src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Background.png" alt="Important Images">
    <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6935544-blue-backgrounds-hd.jpg" alt="PIGS">
    <img src="http://watermarked.cutcaster.com/cutcaster-photo-100482846-Blue-Technology-Background.jpg" alt="ROADS will be here">
</section>
```

Comment: For some reasons it is throwing the images way to much to the right...but I quickly tried on my jsfiddle and it works perfectly. Actually it works without the jquery code?
Was there any extra reason to use jQuery?

Comment: @WosleyAlarico The `JQuery` was to handle the clicks.

Comment: Oh yes I see. Thanks for the hand

Comment: @WosleyAlarico You are most welcome :) Do not forget to put a `position: relative` to the container so the images will be absolute positioned taking as reference it. In this case it is working but it can give you to the wrong way if you have more positioned elements in the webpage.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not being able to figure out what exactly is wrong.if you can see on my snippet,it all works...but when I do the same in my text editor, the images go way to big,one after each other, and the last one appears in small dimension.

https://jsfiddle.net/5gw8cuqm/1/

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Can you post the code that you have right now in your text editor in the jsfiddle please?

Comment: Just figured that I sent the wrong link. This is what I Have on my text editor: https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/t0fhbark/

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Ok. Look it now. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0fhbark/1/). I have set `position: relative` to the container and set a height to the `#slider`. I also have set a `height`/`width` to the `html` and `body` tags to fill all the available space.

Comment: For some reason it all works on jsfiddle but not on brackets or notepad++. I tried different browsers and nothing changes.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Have you tried to copy the code of the JSFiddle in a new one file of Notepad?

Comment: Yes. I opened a new file and pasted exactly the same code.Really strange

Comment: @WosleyAlarico What is the ouptput that you are getting?

Comment: The images appear in extremely high dimension that it even creates a horizontal scroll bar.In addition to that,the third image appears small. They images appear in block.
The widths are probable 5000px!

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Have you linked your styles to your html file? It seems that it is not getting your styles properly.

Comment: I would have sent you an icon placing my hand on top of my head if there was one. Got so frustrated and forgot about that little detail.
It works yes.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico I am glad that it has worked for you. Sometimes the minor things are the worst problems that you face in. Just because you take for granted that it is always correct.

Comment: Indeed you are right. I know we spent way too much time because of that but would be glad if you can tell me how do I decrease the height of the image without allowing the content of the image to disappear?
Because when I set the height to specific value,the height changes but I can see that it hides the image accordingly.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Look this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0fhbark/2/) to see if it is what you are looking for. When you set an `overflow: hidden`, if the image is bigger than the container, then the content that overflows will be hidden. In this case I have changed the height of the container and the image will fits to the full available space.

Comment: Yes. It did not come to my mind setting the height of the image to 100% as well. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="slider">
    <img src="image/291H.jpg" id="one" alt="Important Images">
    <img src="image/305H.jpg" id="two" alt="PIGS">
    <img src="image/251H.jpg" id="three" alt="ROADS will be here">
</section>
```

your css:

```
img{
    width:100%;
}
#slider{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img#one{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

img#two{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

img#three{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: updated. I had just randomized it. If someone gets the point, then he can update it.

Comment: unfortunately nothing works. Tried as you can see on my snippet which it works there(on the jsfiddle) but not when I go back to the normal text editor.